# Unsupervised classification of large binary/boolean dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning, binary-data

I have a large dataset of binary data.  I have ~15,000 rows and ~2000 columns, wit the data itself consisting of a binary variable.  I would like to classify all 15,000 rows into *n* groups, by using their 2,000 values across the columns.

I have considered using random forest classification, as well as running a PCA and seeing which groups of rows co-vary with the first few principle components, but neither of these approaches seem ideal.  I am wondering if there is some other machine learning technique that is best when dealing with binary/boolean data.

I'm very comfortable in R, and would especially appreciate any recommendations of specific packages.